# use of + sign in Google Adwords

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to do a phrase match search like "warrenton home values" but I'd like to make sure home+values stay in that order but can be switched so that "home values warrenton" and "warrenton home values" will both trigger.

I thought the + sign would "chain" the two words, home+values together but after a chat with a Google rep I find myself more confused than before.  What is the best way to achieve this?

Will this phrase also trigger *warrenton island home values* keyword search or does the use of quotes only match words found within the quotes?  I need to make sure I keep warrenton in the search phrase to avoid wasting budget on triggering ads outside of the geographic area.

Comment: Why not making it simply match all the words, no matter the order, and make Google take care of the rest?

Comment: @Jonast92 you mean exact phrase match?  Then I'd need to make two entries which I am trying to avoid as I have about 150 of these instances which would double the work to 300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a modifier, the plus sign on your keyboard (+), to any of the terms that are part of your broad match keyword phrase. By adding a modifier, your ads can only show when someone's search contains those modified terms, or close variations of the modified terms, in any order. The modifier won't work with phrase match or exact match keywords.

Example: +women's +hats
Example Search:  hats for women

Unlike broad match keywords, modified broad match keywords won't show your ad for synonyms or related searches. For this reason, it adds an additional level of control. Using broad match modifier is a good choice if you want to increase relevancy even if it means you might get less ad traffic than broad match.

More information here:  https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2497836?hl=en&authuser=1